# Is there an alternative to ~ on bash?

Tags: windows, bash, git

My keyboard doesn't have a `~` key, and the Git Bash on Windows doesn't allow me to type that symbol with `Alt-###` combinations nor to paste it in. How can I do this?

Comment: What keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: Note that although the question explicitly states _Git Bash on Windows_, this question was originally erroneously tagged "Linux".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$HOME`, as e.g. in

```
cd $HOME
```

Comment: Admittedly a stupid example, as `cd` also works.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an on screen keyboard with a qwerty lay-out.

In linux you can apparently do the following:

> Alt+F2
>
> type onboard
>
> Enter

Don't know if this is true, I don't use Linux myself.

Comment: I'm actually using windows.

Comment: I'm sorry, the tag said linux. In that case, just execute osk.exe